# Таймер с уведомлением для телеграм-бота

Tags: python

**Задача:** реализовать уведомление пользователя Telegram через разные промежутки времени (заданные в системе) посредством Telegram бота, с записью и удалением информации об уведомлении в БД.

**Пример:** пользователь выбирает функцию с временем, например 10 минут. Задача записывается в БД, через 10 минут, пользователю приходит уведомление и задача в БД помечается как отмеченная.

Проблема с которой я столкнулся и пока не могу решить, пробовал много способов, но если бота перезапустить задача в БД не отмечается, пользователь остается без уведомления.

Возможно, есть какой-то способ передать задачу в отдельную библиотеку независимую от библиотеки телеграм бота, чтобы через нужный промежуток времени отметил задачу в БД ?

Comment: попробуйте в добавить в БД еще одно значение, конечное время которые код сразу же просчитал, а потом в промежутке 1 минута+- проверяйте значение из БД и время сейчяс

Comment: Такая реализация была ранее, была задача в кроне на каждые 10 минут. Хотел как раз уйти от этого. Есть вероятность, что потребуются уведомления менее минуты. Хотя вместо крона можно использовать цикл и проверять с любым промежутком, об этом я почему-то не думал.

Comment: еще есть вариант создать отдельный файл секундомер, и если прошло 10 минут переменная меняется на True, если переменная == True отсылать текст пользователю